# Rails routing with roles, how do I set it up?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, roles

This is more of a conceptual question...

I'm starting on an app that will have a few roles (e.g. employee, manager, store_manager). Each role will view/edit/destroy in different ways from each other. When a manager is editing an employee the view will be very different than when a store_manager is editing.

My thinking was to namespace many of the models with the role. Like:

```
namespace :store_manger do
  resources :users
  resources :widgets
end

namespace :manager do
  resources :users
  resources :widgets
end
```

This seems to be a much cleaner method than creating all the *if can? :update, @article* all over the controllers and views.

So, is my thinking on track?

Are there any pitfalls to using this method that I need to be aware of?

Or, is there a better way to organize this?

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, grouping different roles into the same view/controllers doesn't make much sense in this case since the views are all different. Even if you need to share views later on, you can just render the same layout.